# How to setup 2017 angular 2 seed with xampp

Tags: angular, xampp

I followed the setup on [angular's website](https://www.angular.io).

How to correctly set up the node_modules when using xampp as my server?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to setup angular2 app via xampp because xampp is suitable for making backend application using php and mysql. angular is a frontend app, so maintain your frontend code separately from your backend code.